# Prolog - why does variable not get bound?

Tags: list, prolog

I have defined a goal lowerpartition/3 as follows:

```
lowerpartition(X,P,Z) :- var(Z),!,lowerpartition(X,P,[]).
lowerpartition([],_,_).
lowerpartition([X|Xs],P,Z) :- X=<P, lowerpartition(Xs,P,[X|Z]).
lowerpartition([X|Xs],P,Z) :- X>P, lowerpartition(Xs,P,Z).
```

when I call

```
lowerpartition([1,2,3,4,5],3,X).
```

I expect X to be bound to the list [3,2,1], but Prolog just returns false. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing an accumulator-based approach with a stack based approach.
Your first clause:

```
lowerpartition(X,P,Z) :- var(Z),!,lowerpartition(X,P,[]).
```

will leave `Z` uninstantiated, it is not used after checking that it is a variable therfore it won't be unified...

Try this:

```
lowerpartition([], _, []).
lowerpartition([X|Xs], P, [X|Zs]):-
  X =< P, lowerpartition(Xs, P, Zs).
lowerpartition([X|Xs], P, Zs):-
  X > P, lowerpartition(Xs, P, Zs).
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really awesome approach!

Answer (score 3):

Because you use a predicate that prolog cant unify in the first clause.

```
lowerpartition(X,P,Z) :- var(Z),
                         !,
                         lowerpartition(X,P,[]). % here is what prolog cant unify
```

A little modification to the code :

```
lowerpartition(X,P,Z) :- var(Z),lowerpartition_1(X,P,Z),!. % note the position of cut aswell

lowerpartition_1([],_,[]).
lowerpartition_1([X|Xs],P,[X|Z]) :- X=<P, lowerpartition_1(Xs,P,Z).
lowerpartition_1([X|Xs],P,Z) :- X>P, lowerpartition_1(Xs,P,Z).
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here a DCG based solution: my simple minded test return the same results as gusbro solution.

```
lowerpartition(P), [X] --> [X], {X=<P}, lowerpartition(P), !.
lowerpartition(P) --> [X], {X>P}, lowerpartition(P).
lowerpartition(_) --> [].
```

here is how to call it:

```
?- phrase(lowerpartition(3), [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,6,7], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2].
```

but if you are using a Prolog with lìbrary([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)), then

```
lowerpartition(Xs, P, Rs) :- exclude(compare(<, P), Xs, Rs).
```

returns the same result as above